layout with grid-template-area in CSS
how is it going?
why my code dosen't work correctly ?
unfortunatly it can't apply the layout that i want it- between the pictures below and another one layout with gray back-ground-color is the main layout that i want to codding it.another one picture is my ouput problem for layout.
i've tried to create main layout but i conflicted with this problem:
main layout
my output-this is my problem

<div class="container">
    <div class="item header">header</div>
    <div class="item nav">navigation</div>
    <div class="item content">content</div>
    <div class="item main">main</div>
    <div class="item content">content</div>
    <div class="item footer">footer</div>
</div>


.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header header header header header"
        "navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation navigation"
        "content main main main main content"
        "footer footer footer footer footer footer";
    gap: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Container background color */
    padding: 10px; /* Container padding */
}

.item {
    background-color: #ccc; /* Default item background color */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: #ff9999; /* Header background color */
}

.nav {
    grid-area: navigation;
    background-color: #99ccff; /* Navigation background color */
}

.content {
    grid-area: content;
    background-color: #99ff99; /* Content background color */
}

.main {
    grid-area: main;
    background-color: #ffff99; /* Main background color */
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: #ffcc99; /* Footer background color */
}



don't use "content" twice, consider different names
